# Problem assigning style on external stylesheet file

Tags: html, css, telerik

first of all thanks for viewing this post :)
First let me show the markup of a button.

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Width="100%" UseSubmitBehavior="true"
                                         OnClientClicked="showNotification" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="customButton">
                                        <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbSave" />
                                    </telerik:RadButton>
```

this generates,

```
<span id="btnSave" class="RadButton RadButton_Metro rbVerticalButton customButton"
   style="display:inline-block;width:100%;" tabindex="0">
<span class="rbPrimaryIcon rbSave"></span>
<input class="rbDecorated rbPrimary" type="submit" name="ctl04$btnSave" id="btnSave_input" 
   value="Save" style="width:100%;padding-left:0;padding-right:4px;height:20px;" tabindex="-1">
<input id="btnSave_ClientState" name="btnSave_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Save&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;checked&quot;:false,&quot;target&quot;:
   &quot;&quot;,&quot;navigateUrl&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;commandName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;commandArgument
   &quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;autoPostBack&quot;:true,&quot;selectedToggleStateIndex&quot;:0,&quot;validationGroup&quot;:null
   ,&quot;readOnly&quot;:false,&quot;primary&quot;:false,&quot;enabled&quot;:true}"></span>
```

Now the button render like this

[image]

As shown in the figure, the text/value of this button is not displaying and ya I need to give it some height.

To add height I could,

1. directly Height assign property in its markup like this,
2. or I could use an external stylesheet to apply its style, right?

Approach 01:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Width="100%" UseSubmitBehavior="true"
                                             Height="20px"
```

renders after setting height as:

```
<span id="btnSave" class="RadButton RadButton_Metro rbVerticalButton customButton"
   style="display:inline-block;height:20px;width:100%;height:20px;" tabindex="0">
<span class="rbPrimaryIcon rbSave"></span>...
```

Approach 02:

### externalstylesheet.css

```
.RadButton .RadButton_Metro .rbVerticalButton .customButton{
height:20px !important;
}
```

Now, approach **01** render as expected

[image] 
but approach **02** (i.e using an external stylesheet file to apply style) is not , why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must learn about CSS Selectors, How to select an element( children, child-child and on his multiclass ) The multiclass means adjoin class you learn [details about CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

your CSS is: .RadButton .RadButton_Metro `.rbVerticalButton .customButton{ height:20px !important; }` instance change to

```
.RadButton.RadButton_Metro.rbVerticalButton.customButton{
    height:20px !important;
}
```

Thats means the `RadButton` also contain `RadButton_Metro` and `customButton` it's not one children to another class.

When you write `.class1 .class2` that means `class2` is children of the `class1`. and when you write  `.class1 > .class2` that means `class2` is instants child of `class1`.

Maybe it helps you build knowledge and solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `space`, your class at the same level

```
 .RadButton.RadButton_Metro.rbVerticalButton.customButton{
    height:20px !important;
  }
```

Comment: excellent sir :) works as expected.. but I got a problem there...the Button text is not displaying now :D (I set color:black !important though) why? @Lalji Tadhani